# Display a category name automatically using code in the functions.php file

Tags: categories

Any idea how I could edit this code to show a post's category title instead of the post's time?

At the moment it adds

> This post is in 12.34pm

to the top of the post content.

```
     function add_before_content($content) {
       return '<p>This post is in ['.get_the_time().']'.preg_replace('/<p>         /','',$content,1);
     }         
     add_filter('the_content', add_before_content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would each post only be in one category?

You'd first need to get all the categories associated with the post, and then output only first. Here is an untested example:

```
function add_before_content($content) {
    $post_cats = get_the_category();
    return '<p>This post is in the ' . $post_cats[0]->cat_name . ' category</p>' . $content;
}         
add_filter('the_content', add_before_content);
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: Hi.  That seems to do the trick.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a side question, how would you go about editing which category counts as the first should I decide to start adding new posts to more than on category?  I guess I can google it from here but thank you very much for the response.

Comment: If this answered your question, please got ahead and select the tick of to the left side of the answer.

Comment: It won't necessarily output based on hierarchy so the first will not necessarily be the parent category. I believe it is alphabetical. If you wanted only the root (parent) category then a tutorial like this will help: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-display-only-parent-category-in-your-wordpress-post-loop. You basically get the first category's parent ID and then pass that ID to the get_category_link() function to output a link (to the parent category).

Comment: Yep, thank you for the link and support.  If I was allowed to vote it up I would.